# Give an example of a smooth distribution $D$ of dimension 1 which is not globally generated by only one vector field.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The question is as follows:

Give an example of a smooth distribution $D$ of dimension 1 which is not
globally generated by only one vector field.

$\textbf{Some definitions:}$

The easiest way to introduce the notion of distribution $\Delta$ on a manifold $N$ is to consider a mapping assigning to each point $p$ of $N$ a subspace $\Delta(p)$ of the tangent space $T_pN$ to $N$ at $p$.

Now if we assume for each point $p$ of $N$ there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and a set of smooth vector fields defined on $U$, denoted $\{ \tau_i \mid i \in I \}$, with the property that $\Delta(q) = \{ \tau_i(q): i \in I \}$ for all $q \in U$. Such an object will be called a smooth distribution on $N$.

I do not know what  "globally generated by only one vector field" means?

Can someone help me to understand this and to give me an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the Möbius strip as a line (vector) bundle over the circle. The vertical distribution is not generated by a vector field : if it where the restriction of this vector field to the zero section (the circle) would give a trivialization of this bundle.

In fact one do not need to consider the Möbius strip, but the total space of a non trivial line bundle over some manifold.

Comment: @ Thomas Many thanks for your knowledgeable answer! Sorry can we find an example like as the example mentioned in the attached question to this comment? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568997/show-that-smooth-distribution-d-of-dimension-2-is-not-globally-generated-by-on