# Show that smooth distribution $D$ of dimension 2 is not globally generated by only two vector field.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The question is as follows:

In $M = \mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}$ consider the vector fields $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ as follows
$$X = z \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial z}, ~~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ 
 Y = x \frac{\partial}{\partial z} - z \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, ~~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~ Z = y \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$
Then the matrix whose columns are the components of the vector fields $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ relative to the usual coordinates $(x,y,z)$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & -z & y \\
z & 0 & -x \\
-y & x & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
and has rank 2 everywhere. Hence, we have the 2-dimensional distribution
$D = \left<X, Y,Z\right>$.

Now the question is to show that this distribution is not
globally generated by only 2 vector fields.

Any hint on how to show this will be appreciated a lot!

Also there is a similar question about one dimensional distribution here [link to the result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568918/give-an-example-of-a-smooth-distribution-d-of-dimension-1-which-is-not-globall)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Integral manifolds of $D$ on $M$ are spheres centered at the origin. By the Hairy Ball Theorem, there is no nowhere-vanishing vector field on the sphere, so, in particular, we cannot find two everywhere linearly-independent vector fields tangent to the sphere.